# I need to move cursor to previous input if user pressed left arrow in keyboard in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
$("#tb").on("keydown", ".c", function(e){ 
     if(e.which==37) { // move cursor to prevoius textbox } 
     if(e.which == 39) { // move cursor to next textbox } 
});
```

This snippet code. what about code to write instead of move cursor to previous text box.

Comment: $("#tb").on("keydown", ".c", function (e) {

             
                if(e.which==37)
                {
                  //  move cursor to prevoius textbox
                }
                if (e.which == 39) {
                    //  move cursor to next textbox
                }
                
            });

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script using jquery to move the focus of the input to either the one before or after.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
 if(e.which == 37) {
 $(this).prevAll("input:first").focus();
 } 
 if(e.which == 39) {
 $(this).nextAll("input:first").focus();
 } 
 });
</script>
```

It works for all inputs. If you only want this to work for a specific class of input. Replace "input" with the class.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/h3uhuw7k/